# Save web page as Html error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, filesaver.js

I am using this https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js to save web page as html.

Following code executes when user clicks download-

```
var originalstr=$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",         
    url:"url",
    async: false 

}).responseText  ;
var  str = $(originalstr).find('.toolbar').remove().end();
saveAs(new Blob([ str], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"}), "Plan_Enrollment_Show_All.HTML");
```

I get the response and i am removing a div tag with class name "toolbar" and then i am sending it to saveAs function of the FileSaver.js.

I am getting the web page with "[object Object]" as the content file which got downloaded.

If i don't do any modification and pass the originalstr then i get the proper output. Any help regarding this?

I have taken the escaped html and tried constructing the html by removing the div and it worked.  For escaping the html i used this http://www.freeformatter.com/javascript-escape.html#ad-output but when i try to do escaping using escape() function of javascript i get different response.

Demo of removing the tag with class-
https://jsfiddle.net/SkyTreasure/zfzocuf2/

Comment: You get `[object Object]` because you assign a jQuery object to `str`. Apply `html()` after `end()` in order to get the modified markup as a string.

Comment: Now i am getting str value as undefined

Comment: That doesn't happen in your fiddle when I add the call to `html()`. You will have to tell us more.

Comment: Updated the fiddle link, 2nd variable is $s1 is giving undefined

Comment: The first item in `$s1` is a text node, which doesn't have markup, so `html()` returns `undefined`. You have to match the element you want to save. I got results with `$(s).find('.a-IRR-toolbar').remove().end().find("div").html()`, but that will depend on your markup.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you needed data/table even after manipulation of the $s variable. I guess as  pointed out, you have to say which content has to be displayed. In this case, "div or table" both will give the same result. But, one other good thing is to clone the HTML content(outerHTML function).

```
$.fn.outerHTML = function() {
  return $('<div />').append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};

var $s = $(s).find('.a-IRR-toolbar').remove().end();
console.log($s);

var $t = $(s).find('.a-IRR-toolbar').remove().end().find("div").outerHTML();
console.log($t);
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bozzmob/662e4m7p/)

Another thing,
$t works in most conditions-

```
var $t = $(s).find('.a-IRR-toolbar').remove().end().find("div");

var $t = $(s).find('.a-IRR-toolbar').remove().end().find("table");

var $t = $(s).find('.a-IRR-toolbar').remove().end().find("div").outerHTML();

var $t = $(s).find('.a-IRR-toolbar').remove().end().find("div").html();
```

All the above values give the same result. But, what is implemented is a good practice.

Let me know if anything specific is needed.

Comment: var $t = $(s).find('.a-IRR-toolbar').remove().end().find("div").html(); is working for me but css is not working...